# How to cherry-pick the last sha from another branch in Git with 1 command?

Tags: git, git-branch, sha, git-cherry-pick

I find myself doing this a lot when cherry-picking a commit from another branch.

```
$ git log -1 another_branch
commit <commit_sha>
// copy <commit_sha>
$ git cherry-pick <commit_sha>
```

Can I do all of this in one command, if so, what is it?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Just go with:

```
$ git cherry-pick another_branch
```

This will cherry-pick the last commit from another_branch.

Branches in git are just references to the last commit in that branch, you can use them instead of commit SHAs in your commands.

Comment: Doesn't work 

`git cherry-pick "dependabot/npm_and_yarn/web-app/graphql-codegen/cli-1.13.0"
fatal: bad revision 'dependabot/npm_and_yarn/web-app/graphql-codegen/cli-1.13.0'`. Yes, that's a branch name. Git 2.25.1

Comment: @gadelat I have the same problem

Comment: After switching to the new branch for applying the cherry-pick we can use `-` (hyphen) as alias for the hold branch, i.e.: `git cherry-pick -`